# SAS Do loop to Pandas in creating new variables

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have the below simple but strange sas code that uses array & do loop and creates output dataset with 1 row and 2200 variables and I need to do this exactly in pandas dataframe.
Appreciate if anyone can please help me as how do I do this in pandas? Below is the code and expected output

CASE#1:

```
data mydata1;
 array vars{110, 2, 10};

 do i = 1 to 110;
   do j = 1 to 2;
     do k = 1 to 10;
    vars(i,j,k) = i;
     end;
   end;
 end;
run;
```

the above code, iterates through i,j & k loops and assigns 'i' value to all the 2200 variables for the 1 row. It's just 1 row with 2200 variables finally.

```
All the 2200 variables are assigned values as shown below:
variable           value

vars1 to vars20    1
vars21 to vars40   2
vars41 to vars60   3
.................  ..
.................  ..

vars2161 to vars2180 109
vars2181 to vars2200 110
```

Similarly, I have
Case2 with the same logic but assigning 'j' value to all the 2200 variables for the 1 row output and

Case3 with the same logic but assigning 'k' value to all the 2200 variables for the 1 row output

CASE#2:

```
data mydata2;
 array vars{110, 2, 10};

 do i = 1 to 110;
   do j = 1 to 2;
     do k = 1 to 10;
    vars(i,j,k) = j;
     end;
   end;
 end;
run;


All the 2200 variables are assigned values as shown below:
variable        value

vars1 to vars10    1
vars11 to vars20   2
vars21 to vars30   1
vars31 to vars40   2
.................  ..
.................  ..
vars2181 to vars2190 1
vars2191 to vars2200 2
```

CASE#3:

```
data mydata3;
 array vars{110, 2, 10};

 do i = 1 to 110;
   do j = 1 to 2;
     do k = 1 to 10;
    vars(i,j,k) = k;
     end;
   end;
 end;
run;

All the 2200 variables are assigned values as shown below:
variable        value

vars1 to vars10    1,2,3....10
vars11 to vars20   1,2,3....10
vars21 to vars30   1,2,3....10
vars31 to vars40   1,2,3....10
.................  ......
.................  .....
vars2181 to vars2190 1,2,3....10
vars2191 to vars2200 1,2,3....10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Case #1:

```
from itertools import product
import pandas as pd

i_bound = 110
j_bound = 2
k_bound = 10

all_vars_df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        f'vars{n}' : i for n, (i, j, k) in
        enumerate(
            (product(range(1,i_bound+1),range(1,j_bound+1), range(1,k_bound+1)))
            , 1
        )
    },
    index=[0]
)
```

For Case #2: replace `f'vars{n}' : i` with `f'vars{n}' : j`

```
all_vars_df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        f'vars{n}' : j for n, (i, j, k) in
        enumerate(
            (product(range(1,i_bound+1),range(1,j_bound+1), range(1,k_bound+1)))
            , 1
        )
    },
    index=[0]
)
```

For Case # 3: replace `f'vars{n}' : j` with `f'vars{n}' : k`

```
all_vars_df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        f'vars{n}' : k for n, (i, j, k) in
        enumerate(
            (product(range(1,i_bound+1),range(1,j_bound+1), range(1,k_bound+1)))
            , 1
        )
    },
    index=[0]
)
```